Which algorithm to use to detect the appearance of sidebar on car multimedia booting?
I need to create a system for detecting the time that elapses between the start of booting the multimedia system in the car until the first appearance of the sidebar on the screen. Sidebar has a rectangular shape and is always located along one of the edges of the screen. Depending on the car manufacturer, the appearance of multimedia also differs. I am wondering what image detection algorithm would be most suitable if I don't care about execution speed or real-time work.
SSD, Faster R-CNN, YOLO or something else?

If you don't care about anything but the time it takes for something to boot, then simply record it.  Then you can off-line process that recording using whatever object detection framework you want to use, or is convenient to use.
